# How do I set a value to None with ConfigParser?

Tags: python, configparser

I'm using ConfigParser in Python 2.7 to read from a config file and I'm wondering how to read a value such that it's set to the constant `None` in Python.

Currently, my code is as follows:

```
config.set("Test Series Parameters", "Test Series Parameter", None)
```

However, this shows up as `Test Series Parameter = "None"` (as a string).

Comment: I would think: You cannot. ;)

Comment: Is there some sort of list of values that I can and can't use?

Comment: Well, `ConfigParser` actually creates ".ini" files, and they do not support anything else than strings.  Thats why there are `.getboolean`, `.getint`, etc.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to the 2.7.2 docs:

> When `allow_no_value` is `true` (default: `False`), options without values
>   are accepted; the value presented for these is `None`.  Does that help?